# Left Join one table into group of inner join tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, relationship

Sorry for my bad english, hopefully I can explain my problem very well.
I have SQL as below :

```
    SELECT tbCustomer.fKodeSales, 
           tbBarang.fKategori, 
           SUM(tbKanvasJualM.fTotal) AS SumTotal, 
           SUM(tbBarang.fIsi) AS SumIsi,
           SUM(tbKanvasJualDet.fQty) AS SumQty
      FROM (           tbCustomer 
             INNER JOIN tbKanvasJualM ON tbCustomer.fKodeCust =tbKanvasJualM.fKodeCust
           ) 
INNER JOIN (           tbBarang 
            INNER JOIN tbKanvasJualDet ON tbBarang.fKodeBrg = tbKanvasJualDet.fKodeBrg) 
        ON tbKanvasJualM.fNoKanvasJual = tbKanvasJualDet.fNoKanvasJual
  GROUP BY tbCustomer.fKodeSales, tbBarang.fKategori;
```

Which result as below :

```
fKodeSales  |fKategori  |SumTotal   |SumIsi |SumQty 

ACONG       |DEPAN      |$170,000.00    |500    |10 

ACONG       |HLG        |$1,500,000.00  |2  |3

ACONG       |LAIN2      |$252,400.00    |4200   |220 

ALIANGPB    |DEPAN      |$467,000.00    |1100   |110 

ALIANGPB    |HLG        |$10,160,000.00 |1  |20 

ALIANGPB    |LAIN2      |$10,160,000.00 |1000   |100
```

Now I want to add column from another table (tbRefund) which holds data for refund items which not all items got refund.
Say, the column called SumRefund

I try this SQL but failed, please help me :

```
    SELECT tbCustomer.fKodeSales, 
           tbBarang.fKategori, 
           SUM(tbKanvasJualM.fTotal) AS SumTotal, 
           SUM(tbBarang.fIsi) AS SumIsi, 
           SUM(tbKanvasJualDet.fQty) AS SumQty , 
           SUM(tbReturJDet.fQty)
      FROM (           tbCustomer 
            INNER JOIN tbKanvasJualM ON tbCustomer.fKodeCust = tbKanvasJualM.fKodeCust)
INNER JOIN (           tbBarang 
            INNER JOIN tbKanvasJualDet ON tbBarang.fKodeBrg = tbKanvasJualDet.fKodeBrg)
        ON tbKanvasJualM.fNoKanvasJual = tbKanvasJualDet.fNoKanvasJual
 LEFT JOIN tbReturJDet 
        ON tbReturJDet.fKodeBrg=tbKanvasJualDet.fKodeBrg
  GROUP BY tbCustomer.fKodeSales, tbBarang.fKategori
```

I know the code above not work, how can i correct this ?

Comment: it seems you missed some ( ) in FROM part

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT 
tbCustomer.fKodeSales, 
tbBarang.fKategori, 
Sum(tbKanvasJualM.fTotal) AS SumTotal, 
Sum(tbBarang.fIsi) AS SumIsi, 
Sum(tbKanvasJualDet.fQty) AS SumQty, 
SUM(tbReturJDet.fQty)
FROM 
tbCustomer 
INNER JOIN tbKanvasJualM ON tbCustomer.fKodeCust = tbKanvasJualM.fKodeCust
INNER JOIN tbKanvasJualDet ON tbKanvasJualM.fNoKanvasJual = tbKanvasJualDet.fNoKanvasJual
INNER JOIN tbBarang  ON tbBarang.fKodeBrg = tbKanvasJualDet.fKodeBrg 
LEFT JOIN tbReturJDet ON tbReturJDet.fKodeBrg=tbKanvasJualDet.fKodeBrg
GROUP BY tbCustomer.fKodeSales, tbBarang.fKategori
```

Comment: Thank you, but however still doesn't work, i tried with error syntax error.

Comment: In which line. what kind of error. more info please so we can fix it,.

Comment: Thank you, let me remind i tried this on Microsoft Access, the error given was said "Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'tbCustomer.fKodeCust=tbKanvasJualM.fKodeCust INNER JOIN ....." till the end of sentence line in SQL